# Nofollow on links to Google pages

Tags: seo, google, nofollow

I have a site that includes a fair amount of location (street address) data, and I generate a lot of links to Google Maps using that data.  What's the usual practice for `nofollow` in this situation?  Apply or no?

[This page](http://econsultancy.com/us/blog/3136-nofollow-as-an-seo-best-practice) and others I've found seem to say that `nofollow` should be used for links to content I'm not sure I can vouch for.  I'm fine with endorsing Google Maps, and [this page](http://www.everfluxx.com/rel-nofollow-cheat-sheet/) suggests that nofollowing Google isn't wise (partly in jest).

Comment: Can you explain what you think this would accomplish? I'm not sure the underlying question is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any reason to use `rel=nofollow` on links to Google Maps.  You know what you're linking to, and presumably you consider Google Maps a useful site.  Thus, you should use normal links to it.

The main and original use case for `rel=nofollow` is when you have links on your site that you're not 100% sure aren't spam, generally because they're part of content posted by someone else.  Presumably, your users are smart enough not to click on spam links, but search engines aren't that smart, so they need an extra hint.

Answer (score 0):

I like the horse's mouth on this one.

http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=96569